# Listview header not visible after vertical scroll in Android

Tags: android, listview

I am using Listview and set header using following code.

```
LayoutInflater inflater;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.header,
            listview, false);
    listview.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
    listview.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(this));
```

Using this code header is set but when i scroll listview vertically it will be invisible.

EDIT:

I am also use Horizontal scroll for Listview. 
 Please help me to find this.

Comment: that's the correct behaviour of the header, it scrolls with the list. If you want it not to scroll you should declare outside the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the layout as ListView Header use  [include tag](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) in your xml itself above ListView which will remain as static though the ListView scrolls.